# How to transform a colum into rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXmik.png)
How to transpose Size column into rows as on the output picture (see pic).

Answer (score 0):

You can put both `Year` and `month` column to the row section, while the `size` at the column section. Of course, you can do some sorting after creating the pivot table.

[image]

Comment: To more closely approximate the OP's desired output, suggest you turn off subtotals and totals, and also select the display in **tabular** form